# App crashed when detecting an app

Tags: android, package-managers

```
package com.App.Detect;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.*;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity
 {
    TextView t;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle  savedInstanceState)
   {
        t =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView);
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
       //Put the package name here...
       boolean installed = isAppInstalled("com.my.detect.prokey");
       if (installed)
       {
        t.setText("App already installed on your android");
       }
       else
       {
           t.setText("Sorry,App is not installed on your android");
      }
   }

    private boolean isAppInstalled(String packageName)
{
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    boolean installed = false;
        try
    {
            pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            installed = true;
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
    {
        installed = false;
    }
    return installed;
}
}
```

I am trying to create a pro key to disable ads and enabled premium feature.

I search and found this code modify "systemoutprintin" to t (textview) but app crashes instantly what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very simple to do via `checkSignatures` method :

```
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
    if (manager.checkSignatures("<your_main_package_name>",
            "<your_pro_key_package_name>") == PackageManager.SIGNATURE_MATCH) {
        //act here(if the signatures of the two packages matches)
    }
```

This would check both the things, i.e The signatures of both the apps match as if the pro key is installed.

The method `checkSignatures` :

1. `true` if the pro key is installed and the signature matches
2. `false` if pro key isn't installed
3. `false` if pro key is installed and signature doesn't match

The above method would work only if you sign both the `apks` with `same key`

**Here goes the complete code :**

```
package com.App.Detect;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView t;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
        if (manager.checkSignatures("<your_main_package_name>",
            "<your_pro_key_package_name>") == PackageManager.SIGNATURE_MATCH) {
            //act here(if the signatures of the two packages matches)
        } else {
            //act here(if the signatures of the two packages won't match or pro key isn't installed at all)
        }

    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just place this code below the setContentView method in your class.

Comment: And inside the if statement, do whatever you want to, if the pro key is installed and is signed with the same key as orignal app...

Comment: sanskar you are the great man you just solve the problm like its nothing thanks

Comment: Updated my answer, please check again!

Comment: Thanks man i just solve it a 1 sec before you update your answer overall one again thanks!!

Comment: Sankar i have a one more question please don't mine how can i check my own signature so if apk is resign with other key  app will auto detect the change

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Its like self checking the sugnature that check on every opening so if app was hacked modified and any stuff was done by anyone at last he need to resign the apk in that case if we check the signature of our apk we stop it from spreaf malicious software or other thing.      Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

To check required application is already installed please refere below:

```
private boolean isPackageInstalled(String packagename, Context context) {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(packagename, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```